# Creating a tuition fee calculator with a function to compare residency status

Tags: php

I have to create a tuition fee calculator, 1st part is to create a function using PHP and include file that will allow you to return a value based on what is selected from a dropdown list.

There are 3 choices:

1. In-county: $1500 per credit hour
2. Out of county: $2000
3. Out of state: $2500

The dropdown list is on a separate page that I will connect with using the include file.

#### Attempt

```
<?php
function CalcResidency($argResidency){
    $residency = "";

        if ($residency == "In County") {
        return 1500;
        }

        else if ($residency == "Out County") {
        return 2000;
    }
    else if ($residency == "Out of State") {
        return 2500;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi @kato440 and welcome to StackOverflow! Can you share a code example or what you've tried so far?

Comment: @Johannes yes I am now it came through weird sorry Im new to this

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to return three integer outputs, based on your dropdown values, you may simply try:

```
/**
* This function returns an integer
* @var residency is: "In County", "Out County", "Out of State"
*/
function CalcResidency($residency)
{
    $tuition = 0;

    if ($residency == "In County") {
        $tuition = 1500;
    } else if ($residency == "Out County") {
        $tuition = 2000;
    } else if ($residency == "Out of State") {
        $tuition = 2500;
    } else {
        echo "Something is not right!";
    }
    var_dump($tuition);
    return $tuition;
}

CalcResidency("In County");
CalcResidency("Out County");
CalcResidency("Out of State");
```

#### Output

```
int(1500)
int(2000)
int(2500)
```

However, if you wish, [this link](https://ecampus.oregonstate.edu/forms/tuition-calculator.htm) might be a good start to design a object-oriented tuition fee calculator, which might save your time. Maybe, something similar to:

```
<?php

TutionCalculator::Calculator();

class TutionCalculator
{

    const STUDENT = [
        'type' => 'undergrad',
        'major' => 'comp sci',
        'level' => 'fresh',
        'in_county_credit_price' => 1500,
        'out_county_credit_price' => 2000,
        'out_state_credit_price' => 2500,
        'residency_status' => 1, // 0 1 2 for in_state, in_county, out_county
        'scholarship' => 0,
        'scholarship_amount' => 0,
        'credit' => 130,
        'semesters' => 8,
        'summer' => 0,
    ];

    public static function Calculator()
    {
        $tuition = self::CalcResidency();
        // rest of calculations
        // ...
        // ...
        // ...

        var_dump($tuition);
        return $tuition;
    }

    public static function CalcResidency()
    {
        $tuition = 0;
        var_dump(self::STUDENT);
        switch (self::STUDENT["residency_status"]) {
            case 2:
                $tuition = self::STUDENT["in_state_credit_price"];
                break;
            case 1:
                $tuition = self::STUDENT["out_county_credit_price"];
                break;
            default:
                $tuition = self::STUDENT["in_county_credit_price"];
                break;
        }
        return $tuition;
    }

}
```

#### Student Array:

```
array(12) {
  ["type"]=>
  string(9) "undergrad"
  ["major"]=>
  string(8) "comp sci"
  ["level"]=>
  string(5) "fresh"
  ["in_county_credit_price"]=>
  int(1500)
  ["out_county_credit_price"]=>
  int(2000)
  ["out_state_credit_price"]=>
  int(2500)
  ["residency_status"]=>
  int(1)
  ["scholarship"]=>
  int(0)
  ["scholarship_amount"]=>
  int(0)
  ["credit"]=>
  int(130)
  ["semesters"]=>
  int(8)
  ["summer"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

#### Tuition Output

```
int(2000)
```

Comment: Hey @Emma, Thanks for the quick response this seems pretty complicated or maybe Im just that confused lol.  I believe I just need 2 functions.  The function to determine residency and then to follow the college I attends tuition rate.  These functions are to be in an include file and then used on a separate page that creates the dropdown to choose one of the 3 options and then u enter credit hours in a text box and click a submit button.  appreciate the help

Comment: Thanks @Emma for your approach but why haven't you created a separate class for the Student? This would make everything clearer (at least in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Emma for your approach, I did some adjustments in order to make it "more" OOP.

Now we have a class student that owns the `$residency_status` (as integer).

```
class Student {
    private $residency_status = 0; // 0 1 2 for in_state, in_county, out_county

    public function __construct($residency_status) {
        $this->residency_status = $residency_status;
    }

    public function getResidencyStatus() {
        return $this->residency_status;
    }
}
```

In addition, we have a class for the `TuitionCalculator`.

```
class TuitionCalculator {

    private static $prices = [ // 0 1 2 for in_state, out_county, out_county
        'in_county_credit_price' => 1500,
        'out_county_credit_price' => 2000,
        'out_state_credit_price' => 2500,
    ];


    public static function calcResidency($student) {
        $tuition = 0;
        switch ($student->getResidencyStatus()) {
            case 2:
                $tuition = self::$prices["out_state_credit_price"];
                break;
            case 1:
                $tuition = self::$prices["out_county_credit_price"];
                break;
            default:
                $tuition = self::$prices["in_county_credit_price"];
                break;
        }
        return $tuition;
    }

}
```

In order to use this construct, just create a `Student` out of your dropdown submission.

```
$student1 = new Student(0);
$student2 = new Student(1); // ...

echo TuitionCalculator::calcResidency($student1); // ...
```

You can make the calculation even simpler and more flexible if you change your `$prices` array to a numeric one because you there is no need for a `switch` anymore.

```
private static $prices = [ // index 0 for in_state etc.
    1500,
    2000,
    2500,
];

public static function calcResidency($student) {
    $residency_status = $student->getResidencyStatus();
    if(array_key_exists($residency_status, self::$prices)) {
        return self::$prices[$residency_status];
    } else {
        return 0; // or self::$prices[0] or your default value
    }
}
```